# OpenGL object local rotation rotates globally

Tags: c++, matrix, opengl, glm-math

I want to rotate a 2D object in OpenGL with this code:

```
    mView = glm::translate(glm::mat4(1.0f), glm::vec3(0.0f));
    mModel = glm::translate(glm::mat4(1.0f), mLocation);
    mModel = glm::rotate(mModel, mRotation, glm::vec3(0.0f, 0.f, 1.f));
    mModel = glm::scale(mModel, mScale);
    mMVP = mProj * mView * mModel;
```

With this code, the object rotates around the global axis and not it's local axis. 
If I don't include the view matrix(`mMVP = mProj * mModel;`) It works fine, but then I don't have a view projection.
 How is it possible for an object to rotate around it's own axis?

Comment: The object rotates around its "local" axis. The local axis goes through the point (0, 0, 0) in the object space. Is the center of the object's vertex coordinates (0, 0, 0)?

Comment: "If I don't include the view matrix [...] it works fine." YOur view matrix is a simple translation. If that affects the rotation _axis_ you're seeing, there is something seriously wrong. But your question does not include a _complete_ reprducible example, nobody knows how you finally use `mMVP`.

Comment: My vertex shader: `gl_Position = mvp * position`